Can "connection to child" on a apache server slow it down?
I have a simple web application running on an Apache server. Without changing anything in the code or configuration, every query results in a 500 Error after about 30 seconds.
I also noticed that every SSH and SFTP connection to the server is extremely slow. Once logged in, the 'navigation' time returns to normal
"I tried running top and htop to check CPU and memory usage, and they are perfectly fine.
I also noticed that the Apache error.log file has thousands of lines like the following, all from the same unknown IP

[ssl:info] [pid ] [client xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxxx] AH0: Connection to child n established

I tried to restart apache on my server but nothing changed.
Is it possible that these connection slow down the server?

As far as I know, SSH and SFTP connections use a secure channel, therefore probably client and server check certificate validity and trust chain. If you use Windows Server, you may check CAPI2 logs or Schannel logs for certificate validation errors. I suspect there is an expired or untrusted certificate that exists in the server may give rise to such a problem. Another probable reason is CRL/OCSP points of the server SSL certificate can not be reached via the client and make them wait for accessing those URLs (may be file share, Active Directory location or a web server). You can check CRL/OCSP points of the server certificate by opening the certificate and checking extensions of the certificate which are revocation list points where the client may check whether the server certificate is revoked or not (analogous to checking whether driver license being revoked or not).
